# Snake on Python Using the Turtle Module

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to make snake on my own using the Turtle module. I have come pretty far considering I have little coding experience. I am currently trying to add the body onto the snake after eating a piece of food. I have made it so that when you eat a piece of food, a piece of the body will appear, but I don't know how to make it so the body will follow the head of the snake.

Thank You!

```
import turtle
import random
turtle.title("snake?")
turtle.getscreen()
turtle.setup(500, 520)

#character
player = turtle
player.shape("square")
player.bgcolor("lightgreen")
player.color("red")
player.penup()
player.goto(0, 0)
player.speed(0)
player.dy = -1
player.dx = 0

#definng how to move the player
move = 10
turn = 90
def w():
  player.dx *= 0
  player.dy = 2
def a():
  player.dy *= 0
  player.dx = -2
def s():
  player.dx *= 0
  player.dy = -2
def d():
  player.dy *= 0
  player.dx = 2

def moving():
  turtle.onkey(w, "w")
  turtle.onkey(a, "a")
  turtle.onkey(s, "s")
  turtle.onkey(d, "d")


#the food
x = 10 * random.randint(0, 20)
y = 10 * random.randint(0, 20)
food = player.clone()
food.shape("square")
food.color("black")
food.goto(x, y)

score = 1
#the test to see if the player touches the block as well
#as actually moving the player
while True:
  player.sety(player.ycor() + player.dy)
  player.setx(player.xcor() + player.dx)


  if player.xcor() < -235:
    break
  if player.xcor() > 234:
    break

  if player.ycor() < -243:
    break
  if player.ycor() > 245:
    break
  
  if player.distance(food) < 20:
    x = 10 * random.randint(-20, 20)
    y = 10 * random.randint(-20, 20)
    food.goto(x, y)
    score = score + 1
    body = turtle.Turtle()
    body.speed(0)
    body.shape("square")
    body.color("red")
    body.penup()


  moving()
  turtle.listen()
  turtle.update()
print("Score: " + str(score))
```

Comment: I have just noticed that I have two things that I forgot to take out from one of my past tests.Please Disregard "move" and "turn."

Comment: I just did a search here on SO of "[turtle-graphics] snake" and found over thirty hits -- did none of these answers provide you any hint of how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import turtle
import random
turtle.title("snake?")
turtle.getscreen()
turtle.setup(500, 520)

#character
player = turtle
player.shape("square")
player.bgcolor("lightgreen")
player.color("red")
player.penup()
player.goto(0, 0)
player.speed(0)
player.dy = 0
player.dx = 10

#definng how to move the player
move = 10
turn = 90
def w():
  player.dx *= 0
  player.dy = 10
def a():
  player.dy *= 0
  player.dx = -10
def s():
  player.dx *= 0
  player.dy = -10
def d():
  player.dy *= 0
  player.dx = 10

def moving():
  turtle.onkey(w, "w")
  turtle.onkey(a, "a")
  turtle.onkey(s, "s")
  turtle.onkey(d, "d")


#the food
x = 10 * random.randint(0, 20)
y = 10 * random.randint(0, 20)
food = player.clone()
food.shape("square")
food.color("black")
food.goto(x, y)


score = 1


bodyparts = []
def move_body():
    for position in range(len(bodyparts)-1,0,-1):
        x = bodyparts[position-1].xcor()
        y = bodyparts[position-1].ycor()
        bodyparts[position].goto(x,y)

    if len(bodyparts) > 0:
        x = player.xcor()
        y = player.ycor()
        bodyparts[0].goto(x,y)
#the test to see if the player touches the block as well
#as actually moving the player
while True:
  player.sety(player.ycor() + player.dy)
  player.setx(player.xcor() + player.dx)


  if player.xcor() < -235:
    break
  if player.xcor() > 234:
    break

  if player.ycor() < -243:
    break
  if player.ycor() > 245:
    break
  
  if player.distance(food) < 20:
    x = 10 * random.randint(-20, 20)
    y = 10 * random.randint(-20, 20)
    food.goto(x, y)
    score = score + 1
    body = turtle.Turtle()
    body.speed(0)
    body.shape("square")
    body.color("red")
    body.penup()
    bodyparts.append(body)

  move_body()
  moving()

  turtle.listen()
  turtle.update()
print("Score: " + str(score))
```